# Nullpointer Exception at net.multiplesystem.nosms.displaydata.BindingData.getView

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

```
package net.multiplesystem.nosms.displaydata;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import net.multiplesystem.nosms.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BindingData extends BaseAdapter {
 ArrayList<String> sender;
 ArrayList<String> receiver;

 LayoutInflater inflater;

 public BindingData() {

 }

 public BindingData(Activity act, ArrayList<String> sender, ArrayList<String> receiver) {
  this.sender = sender;
  this.receiver = receiver;

  inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return sender.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return 0;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  Holder holder;
  if (convertView == null) {
   holder = new Holder();
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatbox_listitems, null);
   holder.txtSender = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sender);
   holder.txtReceiver = (TextView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.receiver);

  } else {
   holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
  }
  holder.txtSender.setText(Html.fromHtml( sender.get(position)));
  holder.txtReceiver.setText(Html.fromHtml(receiver.get(position)));
  return convertView;
 }

 private class Holder {
  TextView txtSender, txtReceiver;
 }
}
```

here is the logcat

```
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655): Process: net.multiplesystem.nosms, PID: 23655
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at net.multiplesystem.nosms.displaydata.BindingData.getView(BindingData.java:62)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:655)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5136)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3236)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3580)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3424)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7690)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2066)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2457)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2014)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7870)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3919)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3808)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3456)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3425)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3510)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3433)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3567)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3456)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3425)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3433)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5520)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5500)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5471)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5594)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:137)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-06 06:50:46.840: E/AndroidRuntime(23655):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Basically i am displaying XML file data into listview.The data fetch from XML file successfully and also displayed in listview. But the application stopped while scrolling the listview data. I have no idea about it. The problem is in getView method of BindingData class. please help me. Thanx in advance.

Comment: this one===>  holder.txtSender.setText(Html.fromHtml( sender.get(position)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to store the holder with `setTag()`. The holder will be `null` with recycled views. Add

```
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

to the `convertView == null` branch.

Also make sure your `chatbox_listitems` layout in fact contains views with ids `sender` and `receiver`.

Also, you have two constructors, out of which only the other initializes `inflater`, `sender` and `receiver`. Remove the other to make sure you're not accidentally using it, though that's not the reason for this NPE (it would have occurred earlier).

Generally, NPEs like this are easy to figure out if you single-step the code in debugger.

Comment: i removed the constructor but still facing the same problem.

Comment: but chatbox_listitems allready contains views with ids sender and receiver.

Comment: basically i am in this app i am reading data from two XML files. First XML file contains username and second XML file contains their details. When i select the username it open the corresponding details of that user which is in the another XML file.

Answer (score 2):

A problem is your implementation here:

```
 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return 0;
 }
```

Change it to return real data:

```
 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return sender.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
 }
```

The rest is answered by laatlo.

Comment: How does this explain the NPE?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
  ArrayList<String> sender;
     ArrayList<String> receiver;
```

by

```
 ArrayList<String> sender=  new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> receiver=  new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: If `sender` was `null`, it would have NPE'd in `getCount()`.